# Does PersistKeyInCsp=false; and Clear() method zeroing memory?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

According to .NET [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.persistkeyincsp?view=net-8.0)

```
RSAalg.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
RSAalg.Clear();
```

Deletes the key from CSP. But I cannot find any information either the memory where private key is stored is securely zeroing once the key is deleted.

I looked at the .NET code and [Clear()](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography/System/Security/Cryptography/AsymmetricAlgorithm.cs,76) method disposes the object only. There is [ClearPrivateParameters](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography/System/Security/Cryptography/RSA.cs,1393) method, but it's private one, and is not used in Clear(). Moreover, [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography/System/Security/Cryptography/RSACryptoServiceProvider.Unix.cs,171) we can see that PersistKeyInCsp is not used by anything (there is no reference found in the project) - looks like dead code.

Am I right, that memory is not zeroed?